# Does the MVP framework included in GWT 2.1 make other GWT MVP frameworks redundant?

Tags: design-patterns, gwt, mvp, gwt-platform

GWT 2.1 includes an [MVP framework](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) which includes an implementation of the PlaceService outlined by Google's Ray Ryan at Google I/O 2009.

That [talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) inspired some MVP frameworks like

- [GWT-presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/)
- [GWT-Platform (GWTP)](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/)
- [MVP4G](http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/)

Does GWT 2.1 make using these additional frameworks redundant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is overlap, and perhaps those other frameworks will become unnecessary down the road. But, from a practical perspective, to date there don't seem to be too many solid examples that use the new 2.1 features. On my current project we spent a little time evaluating the 2.1 MVP constructs and settled on using the GWT-presenter framework because we were able to make progress a lot faster using examples such as the [Hupa](http://james.apache.org/hupa/) mail client.

Unfortunately, all of these frameworks seem to lack solid documentation. They all seem to give you a trivial Hello World example, without showing you the essential details necessary to do anything more than a trivial example. The only way to learn is to dig through code.

Comment: We used GWT Presenter 1.0 but are considering removing in a redesign. Still hoping more GWT MVP practitioners will answer/vote to get a more cross section of opinion.

Comment: I see that GWTP creator Philippe Beaudoin said on Jul 29 2010 that "the feature gap between GWTP and GWT's 2.1 MVP classes is a bit too large" and GWTP will be maintained and upgraded for now (http://www.gwtsushi.info/2010/06/newbie-confronts-gwt-guice-gin-mvp-and.html). I guess this confirms that at the moment the 3rd party MVP frameworks still have their place.

Comment: Additionally, Philippe Beaudoin said in Nov 2010 - "2.1 MVP is closer to the metal and will need you to write more code & 2.1 MVP are still meant to sit behind a 3rd party tool" - http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/ComparisonWithGwtMVP

Comment: Regarding example, gwt-platform tries really hard to provide many examples of the different functionalities, together with a larger integrated example in the form of PuzzleBazar. Moreover, the community there is large and helpful. I think the same hold true for MVP4G.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a small website written in GWT using Sring(For Security and Dependency injection) at the backend and GIN at the frontend.

When I migrated to GWT 2.1 I took 1 day to change from my old MVP framework to the integrated one. The example I took as a reference was [the one at the GWT website](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).

Of course it takes you some time to switch, however it results in smaller, cleaner code than with other solutions I've seen